# Understanding definition of Cover

Tags: general-topology

- A cover of a set ${\displaystyle X}$  is a collection of sets whose union contains ${\displaystyle X}$  as a subset. Formally, if

$ C=\lbrace U_{\alpha }:\alpha \in A\rbrace$.

**My question is: What is the $A$ mean, is $A\subseteq X$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is an arbitrary [index set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set), meaning that the cover could contain finitely many, countably infinitely many, or uncountably infinitely many elements. This is more general than saying $ C = \{ U_i: i = 1, \ldots, n\} $, for instance.

Comment: Okey. So what is the $U$ in the definition mean?

Comment: @Kahler $U_\alpha$ is a set, a specific element of the cover.